# is_category() function

Tags: categories, bug

I have category which name is '51m series' (it has id 135). Why the expression is_category(51) is true on this category page? I think it should be false according to [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category). Is it a bug? 
Wordpress 3.5.2

`category.php` code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
if (is_category(array(36, 63, 64, 65, 67))) {
    get_template_part('category', 'papers');        
}  elseif (is_category(array(5, 62, 61, 23, 17, 151))) {
    get_template_part('category', 'icons');
} elseif (is_category(array(25, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 71))) {
    echo is_category(51);
    get_template_part('category', 'gallery-machine');
} else {
    get_template_part('category', 'gallery-frame');
}

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[51m series live](http://proart.com.ua/category/catalog/baget-po-proizvoditelyu/listwpol/51m-series) You may see 1 (`is_category(51)`) on the of the page.

Comment: Please post any actual code (as appropriate). Also, a live link to a page demonstrating the condition would be helpful. (Please ensure that your Theme calls `body_class()` inside the HTML `<body>` tag, as it will be extremely helpful in troubleshooting the issue.)

Comment: Please add the code to your *question*, and not linked from a third-party site. Note: added it for you. Can you add a link to a live version of the rendered `category.php` for the category in question?

Comment: Can you please **add the `body_class()` template tag** to the HTML `<body>` tag, like so: `<body <?php body_class(); ?>`.

Comment: Also, to test if this is a mistaken match with the `51m series` name/slug: can you temporarily edit that category name/slug (e.g. by adding a character in front of "51m" for both the name and the slug)?

Comment: After renaming category to `m series` everything become OK ([proof](http://proart.com.ua/category/catalog/baget-po-proizvoditelyu/listwpol/m-series)).

Comment: I have also added `body_class()`.

Comment: Yep; there's definitely a clash with `51`. Composing an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that, for some reason, the `name` "51m series" or `slug` `51m-series` is (or both are) matching `is_category( 51 )`.

The `is_category()` function [uses the PHP `in_array()` conditional](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/query.php#L3164) to match against ID, slug, and name:

```
if ( in_array( $cat_obj->term_id, $category ) )
     return true;
elseif ( in_array( $cat_obj->name, $category ) )
    return true;
elseif ( in_array( $cat_obj->slug, $category ) )
    return true;
```

The [`in_array()` conditional](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) appears to be returning true when `51` is found in the name/slug `51m series`/`51m-series`. While both the name and slug conditional checks should be *case-sensitive*, none of the checks are *strict*. So the integer `51` is possibly being evaluated as a *string* against `$cat_obj->name`, and matching `51m Series` (or against `$cat_obj->slug`, and matching `51m-series`)

Possible solutions:

- Use category names/slugs that don't begin with numbers
- Query explicitly against category slugs rather than against category IDs

This may also be a case where core needs to perform a `strict` check in `in_array()`, to differentiate between an ID integer and a name/slug string.